# SQL JOIN get data from left table Only even if all right column match

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5. I have tow tables

```
EmployeeReportMarch
EmployeeId      Bonus      Day
---------------------------------
1               10000      23

EmployeeReport20152016
EmployeeId      Bonus      Month
---------------------------------
1               10000      02
1               10000      03

EmployeeReport
EmployeeId      Bonus      FiscalYear
---------------------------------
1               100000      20152016
1               90000       20162017

Calendar
Day_Id          Day    Month     FiscalYear
--------------------------------------------
2015-03-21      21     3         20152016
2015-03-22      22     3         20152016
2015-03-23      23     3         20152016
2015-03-24      24     3         20152016
2015-03-25      25     3         20152016
```

**Calendar table is from '2010-01-01' to '2016-12-31' .**
**Fiscal Year is from 1st April to 31st March.**

When I am joining both table to get data from

```
SELECT e.EmployeeeId, e.Bonus
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Calendar c ON e.Day = c.Day
WHERE c.Day_Id BETWEEN '2015-02-01'::Date AND '2015-03-31'::Date;
```

Output :

```
EmployeeId     Bonus     Day_Id
-------------------------------------
1              10000     2015-02-23
1              10000     2015-03-23

SELECT e.EmployeeeId, e.Bonus
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Calendar c ON e.Month = c.Month
WHERE c.Day_Id BETWEEN '2015-02-01'::Date AND '2015-03-31'::Date;
```

Output :

```
EmployeeId     Bonus
--------------------
1              100000
1              100000

--59 Rows (2 Month rows)

SELECT e.EmployeeeId, e.Bonus
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Calendar c ON e.FiscalYear = c.FiscalYear
WHERE c.Day_Id BETWEEN '2015-02-01'::Date AND '2015-03-31'::Date;
```

Output :

```
EmployeeId     Bonus
--------------------
1              10000
1              10000

--365 Rows
```

But there is only one record left in table. I have tried with OUTER JOIN also but the result was same any idea How to do it.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  "only one record left in table".  Huh?  You are doing a select, this doesn't affect the contents of the records.  Please edit your question and provide sample data *and* desired results.

Comment: `SELECT e.EmployeeeId, e.Bonus, c.DayId` <<-- add a comma

Comment: @Gordon Linoff its just an example. there are lakhs of record in my table. Issue is its giving record from another month that does not exist because day is matching in calendar table.

Comment: There is no sense in using only Day as the Key, add Month to JOIN clause. **Edit**: and Year...

Comment: @Razzak I can not do that I am creating data using database CUBE concept so I do not want more dimension for month and year in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem of architecture, not JOIN statement...

Your table Calendar have Primary Key column `Day_Id`, but You trying to JOIN it by column Day, which is not unique. There are a lot of records with Day = 23 (12 per Year, to be exact). So, You get 1 row per each month in Your table.

To fix this problem, You should JOIN it by column Day_Id (or by 3 columns at once: Year + Month + Day).

Comment: Suppose there is Month or Year column instead of day column in my employee table then ?

Comment: Year + Month + Day. Or Day_Id.

Comment: It will only work for day wise data. what if bonus column contain full year bonus and if I am querying for multiple year using calendar table year column then Year + Month + Day Or Day_Id will not work.

Comment: Add 3 columns, Year, Month and Day. 

If it's contains full Year bonus then leave Month and Day as nulls.

Change JOIN clause to `ON e.Year = c.Year AND (e.Month is NULL OR e.Month = c.Month) AND (e.Day is NULL OR e.Day = c.Day)`

Comment: I can not do that its a multi dimension table with CUBE concept. so more column will just create new dimension that I do not want

Comment: To be exact. You want to join table Employee with table Calendar, to get Day_Id (which used only to get date's string representation ?). so, You try to join it by Day (23 in Your example), but You don't know what Month\Year is that Day? It's like searching House 10 in a city, without knowing the Street... or even the City x_x

Comment: Please recheck the question I have updated it with my all scenarios. Data is fiscal year wise. that's why I am joining the tables for the given date range. As i can write condition like 'c.Month = 2' for the result but it will not work for other two tables.

Comment: Ok, let's try again. You have 1 record in Employee table, where Day = 23. What record(s) from Calendar table You want to get, when You performs JOIN?

Comment: I am using Calendar table just for WHERE CLAUSE so that I will only get data within given time span. Currently day is from start of month and end of month but date can any day within month so I can not pass just days from 15 to 28 in February table and 1 to 31. I understood your answer about Day column I will give condition like  ` e.Day = c.Day AND c.Month = 3 AND c.Year = 20152016 . But it will only work for 1st table EmployeeReportMarch. Do you have any idea for other two tables.

Comment: If You need all rows from Month (i.e. when EmployeeReport20152016 Month = 02), then You can just JOIN by `e.Month = c.Month` and limit by Year. And in the 3rd query just JOIN by .FisacalYear

Comment: Not working. March Month still giving me 31 rows as per date for EmployeeReport20152016 table and Same for Fiscalyear.

Comment: You have 1 record in Employee table, where Month = 3 (march). What record(s) from Calendar table You want to get, when You performs JOIN? I thought You want to get all 31 days of March...

Comment: I am using calendar table for WHERE clause because condition can be from December to March so I can not write `WHERE e.Month BETWEEN 12 AND 03` it will not work. I can do it with using sub query or IN clause but it will affect application performance.

Comment: Maybe You can concat Year + Month to get string like 2015201612 .. 2016201703, and then use BETWEEN ? Smth like `WHERE CONCAT(c.Month, c.FiscalYear) BETWEEN <date_string1> and <date_string2>`

Comment: thanks for the help! I have changed my table structure. Replaced day, month and year column with Day_Id to get proper result. For month I am giving first day of month and for fiscal year, first day of fiscal year and removed that JOIN. Its giving desired output.

Answer (score 0):

join combines matching rows from both tables. Since the day in employee table matches twice with day in calendar table within the range given in between statement, that is why two rows in output. I think if you use any join, it will give two rows in output.

Comment: So is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: you have to match by employee id or you could give range within one month, that way, it will select one day only.

Comment: I can not add employee Id in Calendar table, it has relationship with many other tables and I have table for every month so I can not give month start range from every table. The same scenario goes for year and month column.

Comment: What I meant was your Between Clause should have 1 month only. Anyway you got the correct answer it seems.